# Не работает heroku run rake db:migrate

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

Пытаюсь сделать деплой с rails на heroku,на странице приложения не отображается информация из БД, `heroku run rake db:migrate` встает на:

```
Running rake db:migrate on ⬢ interviewtest99... up, run.9880 (Free)
   (1.2ms)  SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(4432828459770397995)
   (1.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
  ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "ar_internal_metadata".* FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["key", "environment"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (1.4ms)  BEGIN
   (1.1ms)  COMMIT
   (1.2ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(4432828459770397995)
```

как выполнить миграцию postgresql БД в таком случае?

Comment: *"на странице приложения не отображается информация из БД"* А с чего вы взяли, что проблема с миграциями? По этому выводу похоже, что с ними всё в полном порядке. Если бы у вас не хватало таблиц, у вас были бы не пустые результаты, у вас были бы ошибки с кодом 500 по всему сайту.

Comment: @D-side, при запуске на локальном сервере записи из БД корректно отображаются

Comment: А на сервере их просто нет, по всей видимости.